# html automatic input detect and redirect

Tags: html, ajax

i want to enter names after the display with loading gif comes prompt me to enter my age.

i want after entering my age i get redirected to url. any url like stackoverflow.com

i have updated my question to above. but still same problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>title</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">


</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
<p>
  <input type="text" name="myname" />
</p
<label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter your names" />
</label>
</form>
<div style="display:none;">
<p>enter your age to enter this site</p>
<p>mr.myname</p>

<div id="spinner">
  <img src="js/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading" /> waiting for your age to enter site 
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="age" />
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $('form').submit(function() {
    $('#spinner').show(); //activate spinner on submit
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://localhost',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            //  $('#spinner').hide(); //not necessary because of redirect
            window.location.href = "http://www.wdr.de";
        },
        error: function(){
            $('#spinner').hide();
        }
    return false;
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if this is your fully html,  then there is jQuery missing. Please add <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:
I have updated your code. Sure, you have to set style for your spinner.
Here is also a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mattopen/pkb4xs7w/41/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="myname" />
    </p>
    <label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter your names" />
    </label>
</form>
<div style="display:none;">
    <p>enter your age to enter this site</p>
    <p>mr.myname</p>

    <div id="spinner">
        <img src="js/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading" /> waiting for your age to enter site
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="age" />
</div>
<script>

    $('form').submit(function() {
        $('#spinner').show(); //activate spinner
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/your_url/submit_username',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                alert('redirect');
                //  $('#spinner').hide(); //not necessary because of redirect
                window.location.href = "https://jsfiddle.net/";
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('something went wrong');
                $('#spinner').hide();
                window.location.href = "https://jsfiddle.net/";
            }
        });
    })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**edit:**
it was not clear to me if op will use ajax call and submit data to server or only want`s to check a date input and then redirect to url.
If op will make use of ajax, then '/your_url/submit_username' has to be a valid url within your application.
This approach is without the use of an ajax call.

```
$('input[name="submit"]').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#spinner').show(); //activate spinner

    //  here goes your code for check input
    //  function check(){....; return 'ok'};
    //  now redirect if check was ok like if(check === 'ok')
    window.location.href = "https://jsfiddle.net/";
})
```

Comment: am still getting the same problem. when i enter something in inputbox and click button. nothing happens still

Comment: I guess then jQuery is missing. please bind.

Comment: i have updated my question and added the jQuery but same problem. if you can run it over there u can see

Comment: I need to mention, this "url: '/your_url/submit_username'" is not the redirect url. This is to submit the username to your server.

Comment: thanks tho it never worked because am sure u never tested it at ur side to see if it works. when you enter something. it just brings something went wrong and redirect to https://jsfiddle.net/. so am not sure this works i wanted it in ajax but i think its not possible gone try jquery

Comment: @FredBrown what did you tried? What is the url on which you sent your data? did it serve correct and response with success?